# How to change word wrap highlighting in emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs-prelude

I am new to emacs and using [prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude). I want to completely disable the syntax highlighting that happens after the word wrap bounds and have everything use the normal syntax highlighting. How do I do this?

Here is a screen shot of what I am talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Highlighting of content that exceeds word wrap bounds is provided by `whitespace-mode` (which is actually a built-in mode).

The Prelude [documentation](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/#disabling-whitespace-mode) explains how to disable it:

> **Disabling whitespace-mode**
>
> Although `whitespace-mode` is awesome some people might find it too intrusive. You can disable it in your personal config with the following bit of code:
>
> `(setq prelude-whitespace nil)`

Comment: I am not referring to the whitespace highlighting. I have added a screenshot above to show what I am seeing. I am using a monokai them found on github but I shouldn't effect this I don't think

Comment: @JonRose Depending on how it is configured, `whitespace-mode` also takes care of highlighting content that exceeds word wrap bounds. I edited my answer to reflect this. So disabling it *will* make the highlights you are seeing go away.

Comment: I'm not familiar with prelude, but the variable `whitespace-style` is a means of configuring what aspects of `whitespace-mode` are enabled when `whitespace-mode` is active in the event that the user only wants to disable highlighting after the `fill-column` or `whitespace-line-column`.   The default value of `whitespace-style` is `'(face tabs spaces trailing lines space-before-tab newline indentation empty space-after-tab space-mark tab-mark newline-mark)`.

Comment: Ok that did the trick @itsjeyd. I tried to eval my init.el but that didn't update the highlighting. A restart did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Disabling the whitespace mode does more than just disable the highlights. The suggestion from lawlist made the trick for me.